# How to get @Test methods from the test classes, when running TestNG programmatically

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, testng

I'm creating an application to programmatically execute our java webdriver selenium scripts. We use TestNG.

I'm able to launch the classes with a virtual XML file. This **works**:

```
    XmlSuite suite = new XmlSuite();
    suite.setName("TmpSuite");

    XmlTest test = new XmlTest(suite);
    test.setName("TmpTest");
    List<XmlClass> classes = new ArrayList<XmlClass>();

    Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<String, String>(); 
    parameters.put("browser", "Firefox"); 
    suite.setParameters(parameters);

    classes.add(new XmlClass("package.classname"));
    test.setXmlClasses(classes) ;

    List<XmlSuite> suites = new ArrayList<XmlSuite>();
    suites.add(suite);
    TestNG tng = new TestNG();
    tng.setXmlSuites(suites);
    tng.run();
```

Since the above method uses the `package.classname` to execute the class, I need a way to get all our classes; both their package and their class name (We have hundreds of packages).

I use this code to grab all the `package.classnames`. In simply scans the /bin/ directory of the project, converting the folder structure into package names and removes the .class extension from the class file. This **works**, too:

```
    //scans the /bin directory of project to grab all packages/classes

    String binPath = "V:\\Selenium\\Scripts\\bin\\";
    File dir = new File(binPath);

    List<File> files = (List<File>) FileUtils.listFiles(dir, TrueFileFilter.INSTANCE, TrueFileFilter.INSTANCE);

    List<String> classNames = new ArrayList<String>(300);

    for (File f : files) {
        //instead of "V:\Selenium\Scripts\bin\package\classname.class"
        //I just end up with "package.classname"
        classNames.add(extractClassNameFromPath(f.getPath()));
    }
```

So at this point, I'm able to get a String list of all my class names, and I can put any of them into the `classes.add(new XmlClass("package.classname"));` line, allowing me run any of our test classes programmatically. Great!

With all that said, here is the problem I'm facing now:
The classes have different @Test methods. By launching just the class, all of the @Test methods will be executed. I want to be able to extract the available @Test methods in that class and present them to the user so they can choose which ones they want.

I have no idea how to extract the @Test methods from our test classes.

Comment: You need Java reflection: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/ Good luck!

Answer (score 4):

You can use [reflections library](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections) and its MethodAnnotationsScanner:

```
Reflections reflections = new Reflections("my.package");
Set<Method> resources =
    reflections.getMethodsAnnotatedWith(org.testng.Test.class);
```

Comment: Thank you, is there a way get the @test methods from just a class, though? (Instead of the entire package)

Comment: Yes, with a `Class` as argument. See [javadoc](http://static.javadoc.io/org.reflections/reflections/0.9.10/org/reflections/Reflections.html#Reflections-java.lang.Object...-).

Comment: I tried both with a "package.name" and a `class`, however it doesn't seem to return anything, ever. Whether I try getMethods `getMethodsAnnotatedWith(org.testng.annotations.Test.class)` or just `getMethodsReturn(String.class)` (just as a test, I still only want annotated methods) the result is always an empty set. (It's probably not relevant, but I was getting a `NoClassDefFoundError` error until I added the `javaassist` library).

Comment: I'll try to test on my side, but you should maybe ask a new question based on reflections library

Comment: Thank you, that's what I'm about to do. I found this constructor that works, however it returns the annotated methods of every class in my project (and not just the specified package) `Reflections reflections = new Reflections(
          new ConfigurationBuilder()
          .setUrls(ClasspathHelper.forPackage("abercrombie.desktop.abercrombie"))
          .setScanners(new MethodAnnotationsScanner())
          );`